# currency and floating-point arithmetic in Ember.TextField

Tags: ember.js

I need to be able to handle currencies accurately in my ember app. For example, if my app is tallying a list of items, and the user enters $0.10 for item 1 and $0.20 for item 2, I should be storing the tally value as $0.30, not $0.30000000000000004.

For this, I wanted to convert user inputs into cents behind the scenes but still accept and display them as floating point in the textfields.

What's the best way to intercept input values in Em.TextField?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle to help illustrate the problem?  Also where did $0.30000000000000004 come from?

Comment: Sure, fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/seanxyu/L3C4Z/ . Due to floating-point arithmetic in javascript, 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like [sinful.js](https://github.com/guipn/sinful.js) to take our the weirdness of floating point arithmetic. Or just use good ole rounding

```
total: function() {
    var sum = 0;
    this.get('content').forEach(function(item) {
        sum += parseFloat(item.price);
    });
    return (Math.round(sum * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}.property('content.@each.price')
```